# Java Program file.exists failure post Oracle upgrade to 11.2.0.3

Tags: java, oracle, file, upgrade, exists

We have a backend Java application responsible to schedule batch-jobs. It connects to the Oracle database, obtains the list of applicable jobs for the current run and executes them. The job type could vary from calling a Stored Proc, to moving a file etc.

We are testing upgrade of Oracle from 11.1.0.7 to 11.2.0.3. Surprisingly, all the Move jobs are failing (indicating file doesn't exist) post this upgrade. This is the issue I am facing.

Unfortunately, this Java application is a packaged product and I don't yet have access to the complete source code. I decompiled the class files. Before the move occurs, the Java program checks for the existence of the files using "if(!sourceFile.exists())"

This attempt fails, leading to reattempts by the job and finally fails. We have already verified the file and folder permissions etc. I also downloaded the latest ojdbc5.jar for 11.2.0.3 from Oracle's website. But no luck. This environment is on a Linux-Solaris server.

My question: Do you think there is any version dependency on Java or anything else because of the Oracle upgrade?

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The [list of new features for 11.2.0.3](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22487/chapter1_11203.htm) says in 2.1.8:

> Oracle ACFS security feature provides the ability to create realms to specify security policies for users or groups for accessing file system objects. The Oracle ACFS security feature provides finer-grained access control on top of the access control provided by the operating system.

So I suspect the permission to access the file system is missing on the java level.